# How to slide up and down the extra text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to slide up and down when there are many lines of text?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<p class="h1 text-center">
    My Title
</p>
<p class="text-justify">
    my text my text my text my text my text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
</p>
<p align="center">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" width="150" height="150" src="assets/images/products/readmorebtn.png" />
    </a>
</p>
```

How do I hide half of the content when there are many lines, and create a "read more" button, that on click displays the full hidden content, and has a slider?

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Below code helps you achieve it, you have to add your text in a div:

```js
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#hidden-xs').html($('#hidden-xs').next().next().next('.hidden-xs').html());
        $('#dvReadmore').click(function(){
            $(this).hide(0);
            $('#hidden-xs').animate({height: '100%'});
            $('#dvShowless').show();
        });
        $('#dvShowless').click(function(){
            $(this).hide(0);
            $('#hidden-xs').animate({height: '3em'});
            $('#dvReadmore').show();
        });
    });
```

```css
#hidden-xs { line-height: 1.5em; height: 3em; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-12 clearfix">
    <div id="hidden-xs">
    TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst 
    data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data 
    TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data
    TEst data TEst data
    TEst data TEst data
    TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data

    TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data
  
                                TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst 
    data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data 
    TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data TEst data
    </div>
    <div class="readmorehxs" id="dvReadmore"><b>Read more..</b></div>
    <div class="readmorehxs" id="dvShowless" style="display:none;text-align:right;"><b>..Show less</b></div>
</div>
```

Comment: also [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/qk70za4t/1/) here if any customizations

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct method to do this:-

```js
 $(function(){
  $("#moreText").on("click",function(){
   $("#toggleP").toggleClass("show");
  });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .show{display: inline !important;}
</style>
<div class="col-md-4">
<p class="h1 text-center">
    My Title
</p>
<p class="text-justify">
    <span>
        my text my text my text my text my text my text
    </span>
    <span id="toggleP" style="display: none;">
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
        my text my textmy text my textmy text my textmy text my text
    </span>
</p>
<p align="center">
    <a href="#" id="moreText">more text
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: @RameshMadusanka So what do you mean by **hide half of content**?

Comment: for example - :  text text text text text text  only show this simple  text and other text are hide.

Comment: @RameshMadusanka But this answer doesn't do this work

Comment: @mohammad i need some example for my case.

Comment: now please check the code one more time his/her condition is fulfilled.

Comment: @ Mohammad, @Parvej Alam thanks for all.i solved my case.